# Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service': Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found

Tags: linux, dns, systemd, manjaro, resolv.conf

I am using manjaro / arch linux and I see the following error messages in my  system log.

```
journalctl -f 
...
dbus-daemon[798]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.resolve1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service' requested by ':1.4' (uid=0 pid=799 comm="/usr/bin/>
dbus-daemon[798]: [system] Activation via systemd failed for unit 'dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service': Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.
...
```

How do I fix this problem

Comment: It's apparently also possible to run into this problem when trying to run `resolvectl flush-caches` with "Failed to get global data: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found." printed to the console. (systemd-resolved was inexplicably not running, which would explain previous troubles resolving domains.)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This problem is related to the `network-manager` and `systemd-resolved.service`.

After reading the the [manjaro forums](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-systemd-resolved-resolv-journalctl-spam/81280/11) and the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-resolved)

You have 2 options

### [configure network-manager to not use systemd-resolved.service](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-systemd-resolved-resolv-journalctl-spam/81280/10?u=nelaaro)

```
vim /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-systemd-resolved.conf
```

With this content:

```
[main]
systemd-resolved=false
```

### [Activate and use systemd-resolved.service](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-resolved)

check if it is running and enabled

```
systemctl status systemd-resolved.service
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: inactive (dead)
    Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
          https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved
          https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
          https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
```

Enable and start it.

```
systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/systemd-resolved.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service.
systemctl start systemd-resolved.service
systemctl status systemd-resolved.service
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-04-19 10:36:53 SAST; 32min ago
    Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
          https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved
          https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
          https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
Main PID: 21150 (systemd-resolve)
  Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
  Memory: 5.0M
  CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
          └─21150 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
```

That solved the errors from coming up in the logs.

Comment: Next NetworkManager version will avoid trying to contact resolved if it is not already running.

Comment: I had this and started&enabled systemd-resolved. But why it fails at the first place? Arch Linux doesn't come with default support for domain name resolution?

Comment: @Artyom If it can be of any consolation, the only service I've consistently had problems with is NetworkManager. The only one whose name starts with a capital letter, to my knowledge... I try to use netplan without NetworkManager as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the life saving help. Howver oddly, while I can now ping sites, nslookup doesn't work, I guess because it uses /etc/resolv.conf